# Add ImageIndex to Treeview

Tags: c#

As the title states. I need a different type of icon for the different nodes types. at the moment I have this hacky way of achieving that.

```
for (var x = 0; x <= nodeList.Count - 1; x++)
{
     if (xNode.Attributes["TYPE"].Value == "server.point.AV")
     {
         var tNode2 = new TreeNode(xNode.Attributes["NAME"].Value, AnalogImagesIndex, AnalogImagesIndex);
         inTreeNode.Nodes.Add(tNode2);
         tNode2 = inTreeNode.Nodes[x];
         AddNode(xNode, tNode2);
     }
     else if (xNode.Attributes["TYPE"].Value == "schedule.NSPDigitalSchedule")
     {
         var tNode2 = new TreeNode(xNode.Attributes["NAME"].Value, ScheduleImageIndex, ScheduleImageIndex);
         inTreeNode.Nodes.Add(tNode2);
         tNode2 = inTreeNode.Nodes[x];
         AddNode(xNode, tNode2);
     }
     else if (xNode.Attributes["TYPE"].Value == "server.point.SV")
     {
         var tNode2 = new TreeNode(xNode.Attributes["NAME"].Value, StringImageIndex, StringImageIndex);
         inTreeNode.Nodes.Add(tNode2);
         tNode2 = inTreeNode.Nodes[x];
         AddNode(xNode, tNode2);
     }
     else if (xNode.Attributes["TYPE"].Value.StartsWith("trend"))
     {
         var tNode2 = new TreeNode(xNode.Attributes["NAME"].Value, TrendImageIndex, TrendImageIndex);
         inTreeNode.Nodes.Add(tNode2);
         tNode2 = inTreeNode.Nodes[x];
             AddNode(xNode, tNode2);
         }
    .
    .
    .and so on
```

I do not want to add the long list of else if's.

Comment: Do you have 1 image type for each type or you have several groups and each group has 1 image?

Comment: Just one image list

Answer (score 3):

The moment you start copy-pasting code and only changing one small thing, it's time to move that code to a method.

```
private void CreateAndAddNode(WhateverTypeImagesIndexIs imagesIndex, int x)
{
    var tNode2 = new TreeNode(xNode.Attributes["NAME"].Value, imagesIndex, imagesIndex);
    inTreeNode.Nodes.Add(tNode2);
    tNode2 = inTreeNode.Nodes[x];
    AddNode(xNode, tNode2);
}
```

I'm assuming `AnalogImagesIndex` etc. all inherit from some base type; that's the one to use as the method's parameter.

---

<s>Moreover, all of those `if`s can be changed to a `switch`.</s>

Comment: _all of those ifs can be changed to a switch._ - nope, they cannot, see: `.Value.StartsWith("trend")`

Comment: Not until C# 7 where you can have conditions in `case`

Comment: @t3chb0t Oops, didn't notice the `StartsWith`.

Comment: I have changed few into swithch `switch (xNode.Attributes["TYPE"].Value)
                        {
                            case "server.point.BV":
                            {`

Then back to default: if where I need to check the starting string

Comment: I want to be like you when I grow up ^.^

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look like you would need the `for` loop. You can do the same much simpler with a `foreach` and a little bit of linq:

```
// assuming they are ints
var AnalogImagesIndex = 0;
var TrendImageIndex = 2;

// simplifies the ifs
var imageIndicies = new Func<string, int?>[]
{
    attr => attr == "server.point.AV" ? AnalogImagesIndex : (int?)null,
    attr => attr.StartsWith("trend") ? TrendImageIndex : (int?)null,
    // ...
};

var imageIndex = imageIndicies
    .Select(x => x(xNode.Attributes["NAME"].Value))
    .First(x => x.HasValue)
    .Value;
```

To do the rest you can use the helper from [BCdotWEB's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/140541/59161).

Another assumption is that there is no `else` at the end, otherwise you need to use `FirstOrDefault` or provide an *else* lambda.

---

or with even less repetition the *extreme* solution:

```
var getImageIndexOrDefault = new Func<bool, int, int?>(
    (condition, value) => condition ? value : (int?)null);

var imageIndicies = new Func<string, int?>[]
{
    attr => getImageIndexOrDefault(attr == "server.point.AV", AnalogImagesIndex),
    attr => getImageIndexOrDefault(attr.StartsWith("trend"), TrendImageIndex),
};
```

Comment: I have multiple else at the end

Comment: Wondering if i could  skip the node and continue when it comes across a node not satisfying any of the conditions

Comment: I want to be like you when I grow up ^.^

Answer (score 0):

On top of @BCdotWEB & @t3chb0t answers you can use the .Any() condition.

For example:

```
List<string> group1 = new List<string> {"schedule.NSPDigitalSchedule, schedule.Whatever, WhenEver.WhatEver"};

List<string> group2 = ...

 //in foreach loop:
string nodeValue = xNode.Attributes["TYPE"].Value;
if (group1.Any(m=>m==nodeValue)) 
{
   //Call the method for adding image for group1
   continue; //This will go to the next iteration so you don't need nested if's
}

if (group2.Any(m=>nodeValue.StartWith(m)) 
{
    //Call the method for adding image for group2
   continue; 
}

//and so on.
```

### Edit:

Based on the comment you could build your groups for the index you need them like so:

```
List<string> group1 = new List<string> {"schedule.ImageIndex1, schedule.ImageIndex2, schedule.ImageIndex3"};
//group2...

List<List<string>> groups = new List<List<string>>();
groups.Add(group1, group2...); //or just build in constuctor

foreach (var xNode in xNodes)
{
    string nodeValue = xNode.Attributes["TYPE"].Value;
    //another foreach on all the groups:
    foreach (var group in groups) 
    {
        int currentIndex = group.IndexOf(nodeValue);
        if (currentIndex > -1)
        {
            YourMethodForAddingImg(nodeValue,currentIndex)
            break; //breaks the group foreach and continue to the nodes foreach
        }
    }
}
```

Only 1 if exist here :)

Comment: There is one problem with `.Any` - the OP needs a different image index for each attribute value and not just a check if it has any of those values.

Comment: Hmm didn't realize that... return the index of the array maybe?

Comment: Perhaps, but the OP didn't provide enough information to be able to suggest anything about it. We don't know how the image index works or even what data type it is.

Comment: @QANew Please provide more information about the image index, if possible, you can arrange the List in the same index you need it, and use the IndexOf instead.

Comment: `AnalogImagesIndex    = 3; //AnalogImagesIndex   {get, set}`... etc

Comment: @QANew see my edit